# how to restore sql file?

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

I have 2 MySQL servers. Server A is up to date. 
I run the following on Server A:

```
mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql
```

on Server B I run:

```
mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql
```

after I run the mysql import command on Server B - I still see old entries on that server. 
what am I missing? I want both servers to have an Identical DB. (after I export and import the file from Server A to Server B).
Thanks,
Dotan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `--add-drop-table` to your `mysqldump` command. This will cause the tables on the destination to be recreated from scratch with whatever data is in your dump.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some GUI clients like MySQL workbench or SQLyog. Where you can create a dump with drop if exists or add-drop-table in the dump what you have already generated.